# Generating a JavaScript file in memory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an SPA application (lit-element, Google mwc and ASP.Net controllers) that is installed at several customers. There is a *config.js* file under *wwwroot* that contains some customer specific settings/URLs. This file is created at installation time manually. Problem is: everytime I update the app I have to restore this file from a backup because the update installation has replaced it with a template file.

I'd prefer to have the contents of this file in my *appsettings.json* file and generate *config.js* dynamically. In contrast the *appsettings.json* can then be placed in some external directory and passed to the web app via a command line parameter or environment variable.

Question is: how to intercept a request for *config.js* and dynamically create the file in memory?

Comment: Why not just create the file when the web site starts?

Comment: You are right. Since the content is considered static but customer specific, this seems to be a better option. Creating files in memory is interesting nevertheless. I will probably use your solution but let's wait, if someone comes up with other ideas.

Comment: Instead of generating a js file, couldn't you add an API endpoint that generates a JSON containing your configuration, that's fetched via AJAX?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work too, Probably a matter of taste. The js file has the advantage that no code is needed on the client side. The downside is that the file is recreated every time the app starts but that probably does no harm.

Comment: After a few tests I have realized that creating the file when the web site starts has its downsides: on Windows the app runs under IIS and by default the user account that runs the app (IUSR) has no write permissions! Adding write permissions just for creating the file once doesn't seem to be a good idea for security reasons. I will compare with other options.